# Meteor methods and Mongo $inc non-number error

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm going through the [methods](http://meteortips.com/book/methods/) chapter of *Your First Meteor Application* by David Turnbull.

I have a method for updating a field in the database.

`'modifyPlayerScore': function(selectedPlayer, scoreValue){
    PlayersList.update(selectedPlayer, {$inc: {score: scoreValue} });
}`

and these methods are being called from event functions

```
'click .increment': function(){

    var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');

    Meteor.call('modifyPlayerScore', selectedPlayer, 5);

 },
 'click .decrement': function(){

    var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');

    Meteor.call('modifyPlayerScore', selectedPlayer, -5);

  }
```

When I use this functions in the app, I see an error in Terminal

```
Exception while invoking method 'modifyPlayerScore' MongoError: Modifier $inc allowed for numbers only
```

I have used a console.log statement to print the scoreValue variable and it shows either 5 or -5. I have a feeling that this may be a string and not a number but I'm not sure how to fix this error. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: i just saw that you update the question with the `{score: scoreValue}` did it works?

Comment: @Ethaan it didn't work. This is what I had originally but I copy-pasted the wrong piece of code.

Comment: hmm it should work you are passing everything ok, i made a little repo and it works

Comment: i made [this meteor pad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/DKDyceq2GfmghWkmo/Leaderboard)

Comment: I checked out your Meteor Pad and it works great. I forked it and it worked but for some reason I'm getting the same error locally : Exception while invoking method 'modifyPlayerScore' MongoError: Cannot apply $inc modifier to non-number

Comment: I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anishkothari/0738b44207b6a5bdc18f) if anyone can see what's wrong

Comment: As a sidenote - everything you ever read from an input box and send from the client to the server via Methods is always a String and never a Number unless you `parseInt()` it. Not sure about how you populated `scoreValue` so I thought I might bring it up.

Comment: thanks @Stephan this is what I was having trouble with. I am getting `scoreValue` from an input box so now I'm trying to use `parseInt()` to turn it into an int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you added the score to a player with :

```
PlayersList.insert({name: 'test', score:3});
```

I suppose, you could increase the score. But not anymore.

It's because you passed a text parameter instead of an integer.
When you add a player you should use parseInt():

```
 PlayersList.insert({
  name: name,
  score: parseInt(score),
  createdBy: Meteor.userId()
})
```

Now, it should work. Or you can use parseInt() to set `score`

Answer (score 2):

You should change the `Meteor.method` to this.

On the `$inc` remove the `5` static and place the second argument (`scoreValue`).

The method should look like this.

```
modifyPlayerScore': function(selectedPlayer, scoreValue){
    PlayersList.update(selectedPlayer, {$inc: {score: scoreValue} });
}
```

And now you can make the call like this.

```
Meteor.call('modifyPlayerScore', selectedPlayer, 5);
```

where **5** its now the `scoreValue` argument

**UPDATE**

I made [this working MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/DKDyceq2GfmghWkmo/Leaderboard) check you have everything like this.

NEW METEORPAD

I made [this meteor](http://meteorpad.com/pad/hqDRasf2Lv4am6NMH/Leaderboard) pad based on the [gist](https://gist.github.com/anishkothari/0738b44207b6a5bdc18f), and everything its working.

Comment: thanks Ethaan, I tried the meteorpad but now I'm seeing this error: Exception while invoking method 'modifyPlayerScore' MongoError: Cannot apply $inc to a value of non-numeric type. {_id: "
z56mgqK2WGhg8Bw2w"} has the field 'score' of non-numeric type String

Comment: the meteor pad its working for me, im pretty sure you have another error

Comment: and how do with extenral varialbes, like: { $inc: {varItem.itemMongo: 1} }, varItem is a external variable. Not work for me

Answer (score 1):

I used parse int on the score within PlayerList.insert as suggested above by yoh and it works for new entries.  The old entries for score are still saved as strings so increment and decrement do not work.  Delete your old entries and start fresh, it should work.